# How can I slow/control the modal close animation in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

If you set a css animation for the modal open, the modal will respect that animation but, when you close the modal, it disappears without honoring the animation.

I'm confused because the bootstrap docs say "This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete)."
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Here is an example; https://jsfiddle.net/chaz7979/o04pxo88/3/

Notice how the modal slides down very slowly but disappears instantly. Is this a bug or am I missing some css?

Bug or not, is there a way to make the modal close/leave the same way it entered the page?

HTML

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
        transition: 10s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When they say *(will wait for CSS transitions to complete)* what they mean is: *it was hard-coded to trigger after the default hard-coded duration of  closing the modal, **which you should not mess with***.

One of the things bootstrap modal does when closing is removing `.modal-backdrop` after `600ms`, which is how much it takes to slide-up and fade-out the `.modal-dialog` + fade out the `.modal` itself.

Which only leaves you one option, but you need a bit more than CSS. You have to give up closing the modal using it's default method and do it with a function of your own which, in principle, should:

- remove `show` class from `.modal`
- remove `show` class from `.modal-backdrop`
- remove `modal-open` class from `<body>`
- animate the modal elements (`.modal`, `.modal-dialog` and `.modal-backdrop`) exit animation to your heart's content
- place `style="display:none;"` on `.modal`
- delete `.modal-backdrop`

This is pretty much what Bootstrap does, except it actually does a bit more, for improved accessibility.